# How do I drop the entire INPUT chain from iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, denial-of-service

On Linux, I've been building a malicious IP list. I assume the DDOS is now gone. How do I drop the entire INPUT chain from iptables, without affecting the FORWARD or OUTPUT chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables -F` optionally takes the chain to flush.

```
iptables -F INPUT
```

But you should consider making a separate chain in case you ever legitimately need filtering in `INPUT`.

Comment: I tried `iptables -F INPUT` on a RackSpace cloud node and it froze the server. I had to reboot. Not recommended. I need to find a way to not affect their rules -- only mine.

Comment: That's why you use a separate chain for this.

Comment: Can you show me how to add a separate INPUT chain so that I can flush just that chain later on?

Comment: @Volomike: `-N` will create a new chain. Simply add a rule at/near the end of `INPUT` that jumps to this chain.

Comment: you could also manually edit the config file. /etc/sysconfig/iptables I believe and then restart the service.... Just don't mess up syntax wise, especially if your remote connecting.